# ormlite: add to ForeignCollection locally and not to the DAO

Tags: android, ormlite

When I add an object in my `ForeignCollection`, the object is persisted into database.
Which is normal according to the [`add(...)` method javadocs](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/ForeignCollection.html#add%28T%29).

Is there a way to add it locally and not to the DAO?
When I call foreigncollection.add(), I don't want the create() call

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more plain?  Are you asking for another method which just adds it locally and _not_ to the DAO?

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution, if you could tell me the way of doing this in ORMLite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to add() it locally and call create() in a second time?

Not sure exactly what you are asking here.  If my guess is correct and you are asking for an `add(...)` method on `ForeignCollection` which does *not* add it to the database, then there is a better way of doing this in [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).

The `ForeignCollection` is just a view into another table.  If you've added an element to that other table then all you need to do is the refresh the entity which has the `ForeignCollection` and it will be updated.  Another thing to do is to *not* use an eager collection.  Lazy collections always go to the database so if elements are added to the database, they will be discovered.

Hope this helps.